# How can i use Joi valid function and allow both lowercase and uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

Hello guys and thank you for your time.
I am trying to create a validation middleware.
I am using Joi to validate the information i receive from the request body.

i would like to allow only the following strings for example: ['a','b','c'] but also allow both upper case and lowercase instances. (for example 'A' is also valid);

what i tried to do:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
   letter: Joi.string().valid('a','b','c').insensitive()
})

schema.validate({letter: 'B'}) //return error but i want it to return 'B'
```

I have also tried every combination of lowercase and uppercase functions with convert but i could not make it work.
i would like that for example {letter: 'A'} would turn out valid.

is there a way to combine valid function with insensitive so that uppercase and lowercase will all get accepted?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it is working fine. If you run the following code you will get `{"letter": "b"}`

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  "letter": Joi.string().valid("a", "b", "c").insensitive()
});

console.log(schema.validate({"letter": "B"}, {"convert": true}));
```

With convert false, you will get B in caps.

You could see running code here - https://repl.it/repls/HarmfulEvenPhases

Comment: i am still getting error: { error: 'Letter is invalid' }

Comment: which verison of joi are you using? Did you see the link where I have posted the code?

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working well after version update.

Comment: glad it worked. feel free to mark it as answer for other people's reference.